# Handling request errors in OracleDataAdapter.Fill()

Tags: c#, oracle, error-handling, request, system.data.oracleclient

I am writing a client application using `System.Data.OracleClient`. With an error in writing a select query when calling the `OracleDataAdapter.Fill (DataSet)` function, I understand that an error occurs inside, but the program, when executing this function, interrupts the execution of the body of the function in which this string is located. Binding `OracleDataAdapter.Fill` Error event or "try" construct does not fire.
How can I catch errors like this?

```
string select = "SELECT qwe FROM employee"; // 'employee' does not contain 'qwe'
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(select, connection);
adapter.FillError += Adapter_FillError;
try
{
    adapter.Fill(ds, "zak");
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
private void Adapter_FillError(object sender, FillErrorEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Errors.Message);
}
```

Comment: try `catch (OracleException ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}`

Comment: I forgot to fix it, that's how I have it, but it still doesn't help

Comment: do you mean there's no exception, or there's exception but message is empty?

Comment: no exception, block execution simply breaks off at adapter.Fill line

Comment: can you temporarily comment `adapter.FillError +=` then try again?

Comment: Nothing changes, but I noticed that on ```adapter.FillError + =``` the program terminates in the same way as on ```adapter.Fill (ds, "zak")``` with the wrong selection.

Comment: try `catch (Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}`

Comment: I've already tried it. In the step-by-step debugging mode, the code only reaches the ```adapter.Fill``` line and seems to make a return, although there are other commands further.